# bootstrap not loading when my URI has multiple segments

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, jinja2

bootstrap not loading when my URI has multiple segments such as http://myaddress.com/more/than/one/segment

It is crucial that I can use multiple segments because the python code is storing into the gae datastore with different versions like a wiki.  The code for looking up data would get very complex if I just used different headers.
Here is my app.yaml file where I enumerate several static directories for bootstrap, js, fonts, images, and stylesheets.

```
application: easyjobboard
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /img
  static_dir: images

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts

- url: /bootstrap-prestructure_files
  static_dir: bootstrap-prestructure_files

- url: /stylesheets/
  static_dir: stylesheets 

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Here is the template page that calls up all the js and bootstrap stuff.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="bootstrap-prestructure_files/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Course Command Center</title>

</head>

    <body>

       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="login-area">
           {% if loggedin %}
           <a href="{{editpath}}" class="login-link"> edit </a> | <a href="{{historypath}}" class="login-link">history</a> |  {{username}} <a href="/logout" class="login-link">(logout)</a>
           {% else %}
           <a href="/signup" class="login-link"> sign-up </a>|<a href="/login" class="login-link"> login </a>
           {% endif %}
        </div>
        </div>   
       </div>

       <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                        <h1 class="title-super text-thin text-uppercase">Lake Bluff</h1>
                        <h1>Golf Course</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <h1 class="title-super text-thin text-uppercase">72*</h1>
                        <h1>sunny</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <h1 class="title-super text-thin text-uppercase">{{weekday}}</h1>
                        <h1>{{month}} {{day}}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                </div>




                <div class="row text-center">
                    <H2>Assignments</H2>


                        <textarea class="assignment-text">{{c.content}}</textarea>

                </div>  


                <div class="text-center form-inline">
                        <button class="btn btn-large" type="button"><a href="{{yesterday}}">Yesterday</a></button>

                        <button class="btn btn-large" type="button"><a href="{{tomorrow}}">Tomorrow</a></button> 
                        <button class="btn btn-large" type="button"><a href="{{editpath}}">Edit</a></button>            
                </div>






    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add your WSGIApplication from main.app, and your file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` and `src` values in your example are relative to the page location. They need to be relative to the root of the application.

I.e., change

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked right away.  I spent 3 or 4 days trying to find out was wrong.